# stop sending google analytics cookie with ajax calls

Tags: ajax, cookies, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics on an ajax heavy website. I have a timer on the website, making an XMLHttpRequest every few seconds. With every request, browser sends the Google Analytics cookies to my server. Since my server don't use these cookies, I want to somehow prevent the browser to include these cookies in every request.

including  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']); did not help!

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics cookies are first party cookies.

They will be sent as every other first party cookie for each request to the same domain (and subdomains)

You need to use a different domain for your Ajax calls (but I guess it would bring some other troubles, but solutions exist : [Cross Domain request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests) )

Using a path like   `www.domain.com/ajax/` under which all ajax calls would happen, and create empty __utma, __utmb, __utmc and __utmz cookies with a cookie path of `/ajax/` would fail.
The empy cookies **will not supersede** the domain cookie for these requests , but will be [added first in the request order](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.4)

Comment: creating the set of empty cookies did not help. I created the empty cookie, set the path to /ajax/ , now for all the ajax calls two set of cookies gets included in the request header, the empty ones and the non empty ones.

Comment: The URL you call is under /ajax/ ??

Comment: How did you set the domain for the empty cookies ? exactly the same way ? (same domaine syntax as GA ?)
If multiple cookies of the same name match a given request URI, one is chosen by the browser.

Comment: Well, it looks like yes you'll get multiple ones http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-5.4
I don't see any other option than using a different domain

Answer (score 0):

I ended up limiting analytic cookies to my domain, then created a sub-domain for the feed ajax call running on a timer, then used jsonp for cross site compatibility. Hope this helps someone else out there.